# Javascript: Parsing JSON for tree view in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, tree

trying to parse a JSON in format below to get Parent - Child tree recursively and will be processed to display a clickable list in HTML

[Expected result in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLd2C.png)

```
    var data = [
   {
      "name":"Level 1",
      "sys_id":"3b8a6ea81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb9a",
      "order":"01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L1-1",
      "sys_id":"565b226c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcbb2",
      "order":"01.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"Level 2",
      "sys_id":"ca49eea01bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb17",
      "order":"02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2",
      "sys_id":"e699e2641bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb84",
      "order":"02.02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1",
      "sys_id":"15da66e81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb1c",
      "order":"02.02.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1-1",
      "sys_id":"5a2baa2c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb63",
      "order":"02.02.01.01"
   }
];
```

Current function for now is:

```
function createTreeView(data) {
  var tree = [],
    object = {},
    parent,
    child;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    parent = data[i];

    object[parent.id] = parent;
    object[parent.id]["children"] = [];
  }

  for (var id in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      child = object[id];      
      if (child.parentId && object[child["parentId"]]) {
        object[child["parentId"]]["children"].push(child);
      } else {
        tree.push(child);
      }
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

May I get help from you how to correctly display list based on order from JSON? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is your current output?

Comment: Expected output is function to parse the current JSON and display it in HTML. Currently have: function CreateUlTreeView(items, parent){
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
if (parent)
    parent.appendChild(ul);
    items.forEach(function(x) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var text = document.createElement("span");
      text.innerHTML = x.name;
      li.appendChild(text);
      if (x.children && x.children.length>0)
         CreateUlTreeView(x.children, li);
      ul.append(li);
    });
    return ul;
}
var root = createTreeView(locations);

Comment: Please update the question to include a sample of the HTML output you are trying to achieve. As well as the current HTML output you are currently getting.

Answer (score 2):

You should prepare the data with the parent `order`. In case you can't do it on back end, you still can calculate it on the fly. Than just use simple recursive function to render the tree.

Here is pure JavaScript example

```js
const data = [
   {
      "name":"Level 1",
      "sys_id":"3b8a6ea81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb9a",
      "order":"01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L1-1",
      "sys_id":"565b226c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcbb2",
      "order":"01.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"Level 2",
      "sys_id":"ca49eea01bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb17",
      "order":"02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2",
      "sys_id":"e699e2641bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb84",
      "order":"02.02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1",
      "sys_id":"15da66e81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb1c",
      "order":"02.02.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1-1",
      "sys_id":"5a2baa2c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb63",
      "order":"02.02.01.01"
   }
];

function createTree(data) {
  const nodeWithParent = []
  
  // Find the parent for each node
  data.forEach(d => {
    const parent = d.order.includes('.')?d.order.substr(0, d.order.lastIndexOf('.')):null
    nodeWithParent.push({...d, parent})
  })
  
  // Recursive function to create HTML out of node
  function getNodeHtml(n) {
    const children = nodeWithParent.filter(d => d.parent === n.order)
    let html = '<li>' + n.name 
    if(children.length>0) {
      html += '<ul>' 
        + children.map(getNodeHtml).join('')
        + '</ul>'
    }
    html += '</li>'
    return html
  }
  
  // Get all root nodes (without parent)
  const root = nodeWithParent.filter(d => d.parent === null)
  
  return root.map(getNodeHtml).join('')
}

const html = createTree(data)
document.getElementById('tree').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified Oleg's solution to include the collapsible tree behavior you were looking for.  It uses [this basic example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp) with a little extra formatting to add the boxed plus and minus symbols:

```js
const data = [
   {
      "name":"Level 1",
      "sys_id":"3b8a6ea81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb9a",
      "order":"01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L1-1",
      "sys_id":"565b226c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcbb2",
      "order":"01.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"Level 2",
      "sys_id":"ca49eea01bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb17",
      "order":"02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2",
      "sys_id":"e699e2641bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb84",
      "order":"02.02"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1",
      "sys_id":"15da66e81bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb1c",
      "order":"02.02.01"
   },
   {
      "name":"L2-2-1-1",
      "sys_id":"5a2baa2c1bd034d0d1dcb9118b4bcb63",
      "order":"02.02.01.01"
   }
];

function createTree(data) {
  const nodeWithParent = []
  
  // Find the parent for each node
  data.forEach(d => {
    const parent = d.order.includes('.')?d.order.substr(0, d.order.lastIndexOf('.')):null
    nodeWithParent.push({...d, parent})
  })
  
  // Recursive function to create HTML out of node
  function getNodeHtml(n) {
    const children = nodeWithParent.filter(d => d.parent === n.order)
    let html = '<li><span class="box">' + n.name + '</span><ul class="nested">'
    if(children.length>0) {
      html += '<li>' 
        + children.map(getNodeHtml).join('')
        + '</li>'
    }
    html += '</ul></li>'
    return html
  }
  
  // Get all root nodes (without parent)
  const root = nodeWithParent.filter(d => d.parent === null)
  
  return root.map(getNodeHtml).join('')
}

const html = createTree(data)
let tree = document.getElementById('tree');
tree.innerHTML = html
console.log(tree)

var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.parentElement)
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("check-box");
  });
}
console.log(toggler)
```

```css
ul, #tree {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li, #tree {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box::before {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  content: "+";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1pt;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.check-box::before {
  content: "-"; 
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tree"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any way how to change the + sign to - sign of the last child if entire tree was expanded?